# What are common approaches to meaningful function return values?

Tags: c, return-value

I know `EXIT_SUCCESS`/`EXIT_FAILURE` is typically used for main() exit to indicate the successfulness of a program.

But is it also used (commonly or suggested) for normal function returns? I'm trying to write some "standard" code so wondering if I should use them instead of 0 or -1..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EXIT_SUCCESS is a simbolic constant.-

You can use `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` as well as 0 for OK and non 0 for failure.

Depends on taste, you can also make this

```
#define WRONG 1
#define COOL  0
```

and return those.-

Use whatever you feel more comfortable with, but keep your selection all the way.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'd recommend that you remove semicolons from your defines ;-)

Answer (score 13):

Do no use `EXIT_SUCCESS` or `EXIT_FAILURE` for functions, or for anything other than `exit` calls for that matter.

Feel free, however, to define your own types for your functions to return, but that depends on the situation and the exact code you're writing.

Some common approaches are:

- Functions returning pointers almost always return NULL (which is 0 according to ANSI C, but NULL is a more descriptive name to use) in case of errors
- Functions that return indexes or positions usually return -1 on error (because it can't be a real index, while 0 can, so 0 isn't a good error return value)
- In more complex cases, you may find it useful to define a new return type with an `enum`, one of which is your error, and check for that.

As long as you are consistent, don't stray away from the conventions too far, and document everything, you should be OK.

Answer (score 4):

You should never use `EXIT_SUCCESS` or `EXIT_FAILURE` outside of the context of a call to `exit()` or the return value to `main()`.  The values of these integers are not specified by the standard, so you cannot write portable code if you assume that they are 0 or 1 respectively.

The standard does specify that `exit(0)` and a `return 0` from `main()` behave the same way as `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)` and `return EXIT_SUCCESS`, but these values are "special" in that they are to be interpreted in an implementation defined manner.  That is, the actual value passed to the system may not be 0, and the constant value of `EXIT_SUCCESS` is free to not be 0 if the implementation desires, so long as `return 0` from main and `return EXIT_SUCCESS` from main behave the same way.

If you use these values in your functions, your callers will have to compare against `EXIT_SUCCESS` directly to determine if the function succeeded, which personally speaking I would find very inconvenient.

```
int MyFunction1 () { /* ... */ return EXIT_SUCCESS; }
int MyFunction2 () { /* ... */ return 0; }

// Portable:
if (MyFunction1 () == EXIT_SUCCESS) { ... }
if (MyFunction2 () == 0) { ... }
if (!MyFunction2 ()) { ... }

// Not portable:
if (MyFunction1 () == 0) { ... }
if (!MyFunction1 ()) { ... }
if (MyFunction2 () == EXIT_SUCCESS) { ... }
```

The problem becomes more obvious with `EXIT_FAILURE`:

```
int MyFunction1 () { /*... */ return EXIT_FAILURE; }
// Not portable
if (MyFunction1 ()) { ... }
if (MyFunction1 () == 1) { ... }
// The only way to make this portable.
if (MyFunction1 () == EXIT_FAILURE) { ... }
```

Comment: @Dan your comment seems contradictory to me: you suggest never use EXIT macro outside context of exit or main, and then show the code where EXIT macro one is more portable.

Answer (score 3):

Many of the functions defined by the POSIX standard return 0 for success or a non-zero error code to indicate failure.

A lot of POSIX functions are defined to return 0 for success, -1 for failure and set errno global variable to indicate what failed.  But a global [errno doesn't work well](http://www.unix.org/whitepapers/reentrant.html) in a multi-threaded program.

Comment: afaik most (common) implementations of `errno` are thread-safe - the C standard explicitly allows `errno` to be implemented as a macro to make this possible

Comment: in addition to what Christoph says, many compiler/OS combinations will allow you to annotate variables as existing in thread-local storage.  so a global isn't always a problem even without a macro.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using error codes, using the same constants for success that your libraries use makes things clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it doesn't matter.

Comment: I knew the downvote is coming. Apparently, it does matter to some ;-)

Comment: It is of doubtful nature, but even that doesn't deserve downvote, I believe.

Comment: Upvoted because what *does* matter is knowing what the function you're calling returns and how to handle that value correctly.  Library functions don't follow any consistent set of rules, so inventing rules will always run foul of a few of them.

Comment: very true. One of the answers here almost sensibly suggests using the same convention like libraries, but it is hard to stick with libraries  that use the same convention, so knowing what you're doing is important. Actually, it would be important even if libraries were consistent ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't use the EXIT_* macros for functions because:

- Some of my functions need to return a signed errno on failure
- Some of my functions need to return the # of bytes read or written
- I prefer to handle errors with a typed callback function pointer
- I like to remain consistent

Now, we come to main():

- POSIX Says you can exit with a value of 0 - 255. Its very, very useful to return a meaningful exit status rather than just success or failure. This helps make scripts more intelligent. In this regard, only EXIT_SUCCESS is useful.